# Why are .NET Framework System.* dependencies added as nuget packages?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget, nuget-package

When I add a Microsoft nuget package (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) to my .NET Framework 4.7.2 Class Library, Visual Studio 2019 also adds System.* dependencies as nuget packages, why?

[image: System.* dependencies as Nuget packages]

I would have thought these System.* were already a part of .NET Framework such as System.IO, System.Net.WebSockets and System.Security.* - They are also cluttering the package.config.

- Why are these added as Nuget packages?
- What is the advantage this?
- Could I remove them from Nuget and reference them from .NET Framework?
- Should I?